# To play one of the Catan expansion extensions do I need the extended version of the base game?

Tags: catan, catan-explorers-pirates

I’ve got the base version of catan and was going to buy the explorers and pirates expansion and the relevant extension for extra players. Do I also need to buy the extension of the base game?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the American editions (by Mayfair IIRC?), but for the German editions by Kosmos the answer is yes. The base game as well as the expansions had the material for 3 and 4 players, and all expansions and the base game each had an individual extension for 5th and 6th player.
The expansions and their 5/6-extensions only contain the additional material, you are supposed to use the roads, settlements and cities from base game, so you need the base game's 5/6-extension, too.

Comment: Yes, this is also true for the American editions as well:  If you want to play an expansion with 5 or 6 players, you would need the 5-6 player extension for both the expansion and the base game.

Comment: Also, Mayfair was the American publisher until 2016 when they transferred it to Asmodee, which created a subsidiary, Catan Studio to handle all the Catan-related products.  Mayfair shut down in 2018 after selling all its assets to Asmodee.